# See available dates in datepicker jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I would like to use this date picker:

http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

But I want to mark dates based on a database query. So if I click on the date picker I can see the days that are not used and thus red coloured, and not click-able.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must implement a function which knows about the locked dates. This function is registered with [`beforeShowDay`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay). Since you need to run this JavaScript client side you will most likely produce an array of available/blocked days and have the JS function use it - this is faster than doing a server round trip in that callback.